# SugarCRM Incorrect date format in scheduled email

Tags: php, date, email, cron, sugarcrm

I am working on SugarCRM since past two and a half month so I am new to SugarCRM.

Now coming to question I am using Sugar Sell 10.2.

I have one job in scheduler running at interval of 5 min. This job sends an email regarding Quote to assigned user. I am using a PMSE template here and it contains one date field(expected close date). Now the issue is Date which i am getting in email is in dd-mm-yyyy but it should be mm-dd-yyyy.

So, to troubleshoot the issue I created one before_save logichook for Quotes module and placed same code as per Scheduled Job. I added [LogicHooks] at the end of subject to differentiate it from scheduler email. Same thing i did with scheduler job code I added [Scheduler] at the end of subject.

Now I am using same code and same PMSE template for both scheduler & before_save logichooks code. I am receiving dd-mm-yyyy in mail received from scheduler(which is incorrect). And mm-dd-yyyy from logichooks(which is correct).

So i have a theory that it has something to do with server's php configuration since scheduler runs using command-line php service.

So is there any solution to fix this incorrect date issue? or am I missing something here.

Comment: Did you got a chance to ask in support portal?

Comment: No, I haven't created a Case. But luckily I have got the answer from sugar club and issue is fixed now. Actually, I have posted the answer below but it is deleted by the moderator. I asked question on both platform because I thought sugar club has very few members and I wasn't sure I would get reply So posted here also. I don't have enough reputation to vote for undelete.